# How to view application queries in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to view all the application queries in MySQL. I've tried:

1. execute `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`
2. execute `SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';`
3. take a look at the table mysql.general_log

But only shows me the queries I RUN when logged in.